# Better way to initialize a class variable

Tags: php, class, initialization

I have been searching for a while but I could not find the answer, what are the differences between these two ways of inicialize a variable class in PHP?:(if there are)

```php
class MyClass
{
    private $myVariable='something';

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $myVariable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myVariable='something';
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `$this->myVariable='something'`.

Comment: With the latter you can pass the value in when you instantiate the class. As in: $a = new MyClass('something'); Then the constructor will assign it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See this scenario**:

```
class Parent {
    protected $property1; // Not set
    protected $property2 = '2'; // Set to 2
    public function __construct(){
        $this->property1 = '1'; // Set to 1
    }
} // class Parent;

class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct(){
        // Child CHOOSES to call parent constructor
        parent::__construct(); // optional call (what if skipped)
        // but if he does not, ->property1 remains unset!
    }
} // class Child;
```

This is a difference between the two calls. parent::__construct() is optional for child classes that inherit from a parent. So:

- if you have **scalar** (as in `is_scalar()`) **properties** that need to be preset, do it in the **class definition** to be sure that they exist in child classes too.
- if you **properties that depend on arguments or are optional**, put them in the **constructor**.

*It all depends on how you design your code's functionality.*

**There's no right of wrong here, it's only what's right for you.**

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to initialize the variable with a default value *inside* the class, choose method 1.
- If you want to initialize the variable with a *outside* value, pass the variable through the constructor and choose method 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use constant values if you don't choose to initialize the variable in the constructor. Here a little example:

```
define('MY_CONSTANT', 'value');

class MyClass
{ 
    // these will work
    private $myVariable = 'constant value';
    private $constant = MY_CONSTANT;
    private $array = Array('value1', 'value2');

    // the following won't work
    private $myOtherVariable = new stdClass();
    private $number = 1 + 2;
    private $static_method = self::someStaticMethod();

    public function __construct($param1 = '')
    {
        $this->myVariable = $param1;

        // in here you're not limited
        $this->myOtherVariable = new stdClass();
        $this->number = 1 + 2;
        $this->static_method = self::someStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Take a look at this Manual Page to see what values are allowed to be directly assinged to properties: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

There may be more differences ...

Comment: Yes I knew that, thanks for your answer, any more differences?

Comment: Not constant values but SCALAR values as in is_scalar() or NULLs as in is_null().

Answer (score 1):

I like to do it somewhat like the second way to facilitate lazy-loading. Simple values I will set when declaring the member variable.

```
class WidgetCategory
{
    /** @var array */
    private $items;

    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        if (is_null($this->items)) {
            $this->items = array();
            /* build item array */
        }
        return $this->items;
    }
}
```